# Marklogic unable to return search response for super database

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-7

I am using MarkLogic 7. I have a an app server endpoint called Mysearch that is attached to a database called SuperDb. This SuperDb has a sub database called SubDb.

I have a user that has rights to read documents, execute xquery. When i log into the qconsole using this user i have no problem running a search query using the search:search library and i get a response of documents matching my search term.

However if i use a rest client and call the app server endpoint, this endpoint is running a module that internally is doing a search using search:search. Nothing is returned in the search results.

I have no idea why the same query is performing differently on the app server and qconsole. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest start with checking the document permissions on the rest endpoint, and all custom modules it is using..

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same user id to login for the app server as well as QConsole?  If your answer is no, you need to add more privileges to the user id that you use for app server login.